# .htaccess rewrite rules grtting error in cpanle error log called autoindex:error

Tags: php, .htaccess, server, cpanel

This errors are repeating again and again in my c penal server my .htaccess code is like this and bellow the code i have added my errors in cpanel

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule dir_module>
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_authz_host.c>
Satisfy any
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine on
AddDefaultCharset Off

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

The error is:

```
[Sun Oct 21 07:51:15.337451 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 2900243:tid 139861235275520] [client 207.46.13.109:6818] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/lkxsvek9g963/public_html/ico/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive

[Sat Oct 20 12:41:53.883794 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 2710513:tid 139861465175808] [client 94.130.216.183:53586] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/lkxsvek9g963/public_html/ico/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

Answer (score 1):

You could start with a better title for the question, "Can anyone help me to resolve this problem?" could be applied to each post and is there for redundant and doesn't describe your problem.

I also hope the quotes in your `.htaccess` are not really part of the file.

The error message already tells what the problem is. `index.html` and `index.php` are not present in the directory, and  generating a list of the files (server-generated directory index) is disabled.

**Edit**

Based on the comment regarding certain directories, it seems a better question would be "What tries to reference the `/ico` directory instead of a file in that directory?"

Comment: but some html folder like img and css do not have index.html or index.php files so how do i disable what rules i need to write in .htaccess

Comment: You could start with describing what you want to achieve. I added a guess about what your problem might be.

Comment: i just want to stop appearing that autoindex error from my server log any how the code in my .htaccess file i already mentioned above tell me if u have any rules to write in .htaccess which can remove this error

Comment: So you just want to remove the symptom, not the cause? Add an empty `index.html` file to the directory.